# Y-scrollbar for full-screen material dialog is overlapped with page-y-scrollbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm making material dialog which takes full screen. Its content is bigger than screen height, thus, it has y-axis scroll bar. But, the page also is bigger then screen height, and it also has y-scroll bar.

**The problem:** pages-y-scrollbar (which belongs to html tag) overlaps dialog-y-scrollbar. If I move my dialog -20px left, I see both the scrollbars.

**The goal is:**

- dialog-y-scrollbar should be visible.
- page-y-scrollbar should hidden or overlapped with dialog-y-scrollbar.

**Additions:**
I'm using

```
scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block(),
```

and it adds .cdk-global-scrollblock class to html tag of the page with style:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

If I disable it in devtools, everything gets fine!

**So, the question is:**
What is the best angular- and material- approach to overlap page-y-scrollbar with dialog-y-scrollbar in full-screen mat-dialog? Or should I just conditionally set and remove this css rule:

```
html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

As @Martin suggested: here are styles for dialog div container
[image: styles for dialog div container]

Comment: This might be a box sizing issue; try setting `box-sizing: border-box;` on one or both of these elements

Comment: Or you may have set a width based on the viewport size rather than the window size?

Comment: No, this doesn't work, as the dialog element has fixed positioning :(

Comment: I've just checked, no vh/vw found

Comment: Please update your question with these details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using hooks:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body.parentElement, 'no-scroll');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body.parentElement, 'no-scroll');
  }
```

css:

```
.no-scroll {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```